# DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString() "x years ago"

Tags: android

I'm expecting "x years ago" but all I'm getting returned is "25 Apr 2015".

```
relativeDateTimeString = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(simpleDateFormat.parse(isoDate).getTime(), System.currentTimeMillis(), YEAR_IN_MILLIS);
```

(My values for time and now)

```
time = 1429937303000;
now = 1492464306151;
```

How can I get my expected value?

I would prefer not to install `Joda-Time`.

Using `WEEK_IN_MILLIS`

```
relativeDateTimeString = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(simpleDateFormat.parse(isoDate).getTime(), System.currentTimeMillis(), WEEK_IN_MILLIS);
```

results in `104 weeks ago`.

Comment: for said documentation: "Pass one of 0, MINUTE_IN_MILLIS, HOUR_IN_MILLIS, DAY_IN_MILLIS, WEEK_IN_MILLIS "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As per documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#getRelativeTimeSpanString(long,%20long,%20long)), the maximum `minResolution` you can give is `WEEK_IN_MILLIS` which gives me "104 weeks ago" which isn't helpful to anyone. Thinking on it, "2 years ago" wouldn't be very helpful either.
Seeing the date would be preferable to that so I settled for `DAY_IN_MILLIS`.